# XAMPP Apache - set up environment variables (eg PATH)

Tags: apache, windows-7, xampp

How can i configure environmental variables that are passed to apache (xampp on windows 7) and the scripts? Is there a way to set them up in the httpd.conf?

2 Usecases:

- extending the PATH variable to be able to run the cgi-programm (dlls dependencies)
- setting some environmental variables that the programm does need during runtime

I do not want to globally set these variables.

(initially asked here: https://serverfault.com/questions/830804/apache-path-environment-variable  - but after advise i post it on SO instead: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the `SetEnv` command that seems to fulfill both use cases.

```
SetEnv PATH  "${PATH};C:\\cygwin64\\bin"
```

Allthough the examples i found do not use the double quotes around the value, they seems to be important. If missing, the variable interpolation of the `${PATH}` seems not to work.

The `env_module` have to be loaded to use the command (in XAMPPs default config it is active).